# Bootstrap 5 dropdown button is not working even after adding all the necessary scripts in index.html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I am trying to implement a dropdown button in react project. I am using bootstrap 5 and I have already added the jquery and bootstrap scripts.

This is the code I created to get a dropdown button.

```
       <div className="btn-group" style={{ float: 'left', padding: '12px 28px', marginTop: '30px' }}>
           <button type="button" className="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
               <FileEarmarkPdf/> Generate Report
           </button>
           <ul className="dropdown-menu" >
               <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
               <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
               <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
```

This is the image of my index.html

[image]

These are the links added in the begining

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Can anyone help me. I tried everything referred in internet.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? can you explain?

Comment: When I select the dropdown it is not opening. (That means it is not showing the <li> )

Comment: your `<link>` is not bootstrap 5 (it says `bootstrap@4.5.3`). copy the links directly from the [bootstrap 5 page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

in the `<head></head>` add the bootstrap script link

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```